# HTML button doesn't redirect to a facebook page

Tags: html, css

I've created a website via bootstrap.
I can go for a facebook page locally by button but when I install code on my server, and when I go to my website and click on this button - it doesn't redirect me to a facebook page.

Below is a snippet of my **index.html** code:

```
<a  name="contact"></a>
    <div class="banner">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h2>We are on Facebook:</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
                        <li>
                            <a href="some FACEBOOK LINK" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Facebook</span></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Could somebody help me to resolve this problem?

**EDIT:**

When I open this button in a new card it works. But when I click by left-button on mouse it doesnt work.

Comment: I assume not, since you're providing the actual facebook link, or at least a pseudo link.

Comment: It is working properly..It is redirecting.Check your link.may be you are not providing proper link to <a> attribute

Comment: For this post I deleted my facebook link to avoid "marketing". When I paste my link it works on my computer locally(it means when I click index.html in my folder). But when I go to this button by website, it doesn't work. Nothing redirects..

Comment: What error you are getting on console?

Comment: @SagarBhosale "Refused to display 'some facebook link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use target="_top" for the link

```
<a href="some FACEBOOK LINK" target="_top" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Facebook</span></a>
```

Comment: Welcome.N Keep Going.